# A comma or a dash is suggested to use in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

"This travel app is a series of guides covering the cultural and alternative ***side of a city, the side that*** is almost never covered in conventional guides."

Please advise if I need to use a dash or a comma.  Thank you.

Comment: To my mind, a comma is best, a colon second-best, and a dash OK. They make the tempo in which the phrase sounds internally a little different. I believe all three choices are "correct".

Comment: I'd reconsider "This travel apps is...", by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it (with a comma) works perfectly fine and is probably best for what you are using this for (I'm assuming for the description of an app). A colon might be the better technical choice, perhaps in some formal essay, but the comma serves as a less distracting, natural pause. When considering the use of colons and dashes I think it's best to consider the context. You're probably not writing to an audience who expects technically proficient grammar, so it's ok to use a comma.